# Calculate duration of sets of data

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a set of data in SQL that looks like below:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════╗
║ TimeStamp ║ State ║
╠═══════════╬═══════╣
║  7:10 AM  ║   A   ║
║  7:11 AM  ║   A   ║
║  7:12 AM  ║   A   ║
║  7:13 AM  ║   B   ║
║  7:14 AM  ║   B   ║
║  7:15 AM  ║   A   ║
║  7:16 AM  ║   A   ║
║  7:17 AM  ║   C   ║
║  7:18 AM  ║   C   ║
╚═══════════╩═══════╝
```

I am trying to calculate the time duration for each state. However, I want to separate each sequence of states and calculate the difference for them separately, separating the states that repeat as well. So I want the above data to return something like below:

```
╔═══════╦════════════════════╗
║ State ║ Duration (minutes) ║
╠═══════╬════════════════════╣
║   A   ║         2          ║
║   B   ║         1          ║
║   A   ║         1          ║
║   C   ║         1          ║
╚═══════╩════════════════════╝
```

Could someone please help? How can I write a SQL query that returns me this data?

Thank you!

Comment: what "brand" of SQL please? e.g. Oracle? MSsql? (it can make a big difference to solution options) also: Is there a date column?

Comment: Is there any order in addition to the `State` column?  As you can see, using a simple `GROUP BY` won't work here because you actually want sub groups of the `State` column (and hence my question).

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/ http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I shall assume the need is for MS SQL Server.

To meet the expected result (where C has duration of 1):

```
select    
    state, MIN(TimeStamp) StartsAt, EndsAt, datediff(minute,MIN(TimeStamp),EndsAt) DurationMinutes
from (
        select
                t1.state, t1.TimeStamp
                , ISNULL(ca.EndsAt, (select max(timestamp) from table1) ) EndsAt
        from table1 t1
        outer apply (
                  select top (1) t2.timestamp as EndsAt
                  from table1 t2
                  where t1.state <> t2.state and t1.TimeStamp < t2.TimeStamp
                  order by t2.TimeStamp
              ) ca
    ) as derived
group by     
    state, EndsAt
```

For the sample of data, one could argue that the duration of C is unknown as the state hasn't changed yet. In that case it's a little simpler:

```
select    
    state, MIN(TimeStamp) StartsAt, EndsAt, datediff(minute,MIN(TimeStamp),EndsAt) DurationMinutes
from (
        select
                t1.state, t1.TimeStamp ,ca.EndsAt
        from table1 t1
        outer apply (
                  select top (1) t2.timestamp as EndsAt
                  from table1 t2
                  where t1.state <> t2.state and t1.TimeStamp < t2.TimeStamp
                  order by t2.TimeStamp
              ) ca
    ) as derived
group by     
    state, EndsAt
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0dd7e/9

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention you RDBMS so here is the answer that will work for any DB. If you need a fast solution please mention what SQL base do you use so you will be able to use some specific functions/commands (access to previous, next record,...) needed for such a query.

```
SELECT MIN(timeStamp),MAX(timeStamp),State
FROM(
     SELECT TimeStamp,State,(SELECT count(*) FROM t 
                         where state<>t1.state 
                         and TimeStamp<t1.TimeStamp) as Grp 
                         from t as t1
     ) as t2
GROUP BY State,Grp
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16bd9c/2)</kbd>